# How to open a Calendar in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, calendar, phonegap-plugins

I have implemented Angular JS in my Phonegap Application. Where I wish to open a Calendar in the App. But The application is not allowing me to do so.

Following is the code, where I am using with the plugins.

```
 $scope.reminderTimes.selected = returnDate.getHours();
   $scope.reminderMins.selected = returnDate.getMinutes();  
 var newDate = new Date();
$scope.showDatePicker = function($event) {
  //console.log('dfdsfsdfsdfdsfsf sdfdsfs');
        var options = {
            date: new Date(),
            mode: 'date'
        };
        datePicker.show(options, function(date){
            if(date != 'Invalid Date') { 
                console.log("Date came" + date);
            } else {
                console.log(date);
            }
        });
    $event.stopPropagation();  
        };
 $scope.toogle = function(){

  var options = {date: new Date(), mode: 'date'};
  var options = {date: new Date(), mode: 'time'}; for time
  $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
     alert(date);
 });

 };
```

If there is any other way please tell that as well.